# It is possible after pressing enter key (on input), form doesn´t submit but call some another function?

Tags: javascript

There is a `form`, it has an `input type='text'`, when in the `input` <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed  I want to call some `function`, but not send(`submit`) the form. Is it possible?

And I want the possibility to send(`submit`) the `form` with <kbd>enter</kbd> key when the `focus`is in another `input`.

Comment: Yeah, capture the event and cancel the event propagation.

Comment: Show your code.. What You've Tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to prevent Default action's with form.

Try this

```
   <script> 
     $("form").submit(function( event ) {  
      event.preventDefault();
      alert( "you can call any other function from here" ); }) 
    </script>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cdp62rxr/)**

Comment: Thanks, this is working
`$( "#form1" ).submit(function( event ) {  
    if ($("#tags1").is(":focus")) {
  event.preventDefault();
  enterTag();
    }
 });`